# Ajax extenders & Net Validators are not working after migration to Win Server 2019

Tags: .net, asp.net-ajax

I used to run .Net website on Windows Server 2012 R2, I moved the website to 2019 server and now all Ajax extenders and standard validators stopped working but still the code runs without issues. I spent long time trying to figure out why. The website works normally on local host inside the server as well as on my local machine, I suspect there may be a misconfiguration either in IIS or in the web.config. The current Ajax toolkit dll version is 3.0.2

Simple javascript works, no errors during page debugging

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.web>
    <compilation targetFramework="4.5">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add assembly="System.Net.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
```

Here is a sample that works on localhost and my local machine but not through IIS

```
form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox1" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator" Text="rdfghbdgh"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        <br />
        <cc1:ConfirmButtonExtender ID="ConfirmButtonExtender1" runat="server" ConfirmText="hcnccjcj" TargetControlID="Button1"></cc1:ConfirmButtonExtender>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
    </div>
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ScriptManager>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of research, this problem occurs due to a setting in Plesk. Specifically: most JS validations rely .on axd resources, which get blocked by ModSecurity in Plesk Firewall.

To solve this issue: you have to set the ModSecuirty Filtering to **Detection** or **Off** not **ON**.

Hope this would help others.